# How to make cmake recheck versions of dependencies automatically?

Tags: cmake

I have the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(test)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK REQUIRED gtk+-2.0>=2.24)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(test_SOURCES test.c)
add_executable(test ${test_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(test ${GTK_LIBRARIES})
```

and the source file `test.c`:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
    return 0;
}
```

I then do

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
```

which successfully configures and builds the test. Now I do

```
sed -i 's@2\.24@2.25@' ../CMakeLists.txt
```

thus updating the required GTK version to the one I don't have (GTK 2.25 doesn't exist). And now running `make` again I get:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ruslan/cmake-test/build
[100%] Built target test
```

I.e. `cmake` didn't even check that the now-required version is installed.

So my question is: how do I make it automatically recheck the required versions? If automatic is not possible, then how do I do this without need to supply the whole `cmake` command line (which in real projects can get quite long)?

Comment: The `pkg_check_modules()` does cache the result in `<PREFIX>_FOUND` variables. If you want to force a check with each configuration you could add e.g. `unset(GTK_FOUND CACHE)` before checking the module. It's sort of a trade-off between performance and the convenience of changing the required packages without a complete config/build from scratch.

Comment: There seems to be an corresponding issue in CMake's bug tracker: [0015795: pkg_check_modules produces incorrect results depending on contents of CMakeCache.txt](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=15795). Maybe you could add your example/use case there to support this issue.

Comment: Easy, just clean the cache and re-run `cmake ..`

Answer (score 2):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

This seems to be a known issue: [0015795: pkg_check_modules produces incorrect results depending on contents of CMakeCache.txt](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=15795). But unfortunately this one has so far not seen much support.

So let's take a short look at the relevant [`FindPkgConfig.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake#L526) code snippet:

> ```
> macro(pkg_check_modules _prefix _module0)
>   # check cached value
>   if (NOT DEFINED __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} OR 
>       __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} LESS ${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION} OR 
>       NOT ${_prefix}_FOUND)
>      ...
>     _pkgconfig_set(__pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} ${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION})
>   endif()
> endmacro()
> ```

As you can see, it won't do anything anymore once the package was marked as found with a cached variable named `${_prefix}_FOUND`.

**Possible Workaround**

If you want to force a check with each configuration you could add e.g. `unset(GTK_FOUND CACHE)` before checking the module. It's sort of a trade-off between performance and the convenience of changing the required packages without a complete config/build from scratch.

```
...
unset(GTK_FOUND CACHE)
pkg_check_modules(GTK REQUIRED gtk+-2.0>=2.24)
...
```

**Proposed Fix**

The following code came into mind as a draft to fix this issue. If someone can please review it, I would welcome any comments:

**Edit**: Simplified my approach by merging the arguments into the pkgconfig version check. We should anyway recheck if the pkgconfig script changes.

```
macro(pkg_check_modules _prefix _module0)
  # check cached value
  if (NOT DEFINED __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} OR 
      NOT __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} STREQUAL "${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION},${ARGV}" OR 
      NOT ${_prefix}_FOUND) 
    ...
    # save pkgconfig version and the arguments used
    _pkgconfig_set(__pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} "${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION},${ARGV}")
  endif()
endmacro()
```

If this gets some positive feedback, I will add it as an proposal to the CMake bug tracker ticket mentioned above.

**EDIT**: To be more specific about my proposed change, here is the unified `diff` for [`FindPkgConfig.cmake` version as of 21th March, 2016](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/6f4f90548353d9e329bd4ddb2f7492788f28f0e1/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake):

```
--- FindPkgConfig.cmake 
+++ FindPkgConfig.cmake      
@@ -523,11 +523,13 @@
 #]========================================]
 macro(pkg_check_modules _prefix _module0)
   # check cached value
-  if (NOT DEFINED __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} OR __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} LESS ${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION} OR NOT ${_prefix}_FOUND)
+  if (NOT DEFINED __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} OR
+      NOT __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} STREQUAL "${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION},${ARGV}" OR
+      NOT ${_prefix}_FOUND)
     _pkgconfig_parse_options   (_pkg_modules _pkg_is_required _pkg_is_silent _no_cmake_path _no_cmake_environment_path "${_module0}" ${ARGN})
     _pkg_check_modules_internal("${_pkg_is_required}" "${_pkg_is_silent}" ${_no_cmake_path} ${_no_cmake_environment_path} "${_prefix}" ${_pkg_modules})

-    _pkgconfig_set(__pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} ${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION})
+    _pkgconfig_set(__pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} "${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION},${ARGV}")
   endif()
 endmacro()

@@ -550,7 +552,9 @@
 #]========================================]
 macro(pkg_search_module _prefix _module0)
   # check cached value
-  if (NOT DEFINED __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} OR __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} LESS ${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION} OR NOT ${_prefix}_FOUND)
+  if (NOT DEFINED __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} OR
+      NOT __pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} STREQUAL "${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION},${ARGV}" OR
+      NOT ${_prefix}_FOUND)
     set(_pkg_modules_found 0)
     _pkgconfig_parse_options(_pkg_modules_alt _pkg_is_required _pkg_is_silent _no_cmake_path _no_cmake_environment_path "${_module0}" ${ARGN})

@@ -575,7 +579,7 @@
       endif()
     endif()

-    _pkgconfig_set(__pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} ${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION})
+    _pkgconfig_set(__pkg_config_checked_${_prefix} "${PKG_CONFIG_VERSION},${ARGV}")
   endif()
 endmacro()
```

Comment: If you propose a patch on the CMake developer mailing list, it is usually looked at. Might be worth a try.

Comment: With your fix (both v1 and v2) (if I applied it right) it doesn't work anymore on my test case: it doesn't even search for `gtk+-2.0`.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for the feedback and I'm sorry to hear it isn't working. I admit - after I had done some testing myself - that I don't understand where my code change could prevent the `pkg_check_modules()` code from running anymore. Could you please take a look at the `diff` I've now added to my answer and check again the patch you have applied to your code? And if it still fails, could you please let me know your CMake version and your host system?

Comment: Yes, I confirm it doesn't work even with the patch you gave applied with `patch -n`. I'm testing it with cmake 2.8.12.2. It's not too recent, but it's what is shipped with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: In fact, there're two similar chunks of the macro. Which one should your patch be applied to? Maybe unified diff (`diff -u`) will give more useful context to unambiguously apply your patch.

Comment: @Ruslan Sorry for the late reply. I've given a virtual Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine a try, installed the CMake 2.8.12.2 and GTK 2.14 packages and applied the changes (see edit with unified diff above, for the older CMake version it was just different line numbers). It worked like expected: doing `sed -i 's@2\.24@2.25@' ../CMakeLists.txt` & `make` did check again for the package and has thrown an error. Undoing it with `sed -i 's@2\.25@2.24@' ../CMakeLists.txt` & `make` did check again and found the package again. Could you please give it a try again? Thanks in advance for the additional testing.

Comment: Oh indeed, the diff you edited in works now (although in its current form it's malformed: lacks some initial spaces at least).

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for the feedback. And sorry for the malformed diff. I've added the spaces (must have been lost during block indentation). Just wanted to let know that I've reported the patch back to the CMake team (see bugtracker ticket above, seems to have been planned for CMake version 3.7).